# C++ seg fault as a result of passing struct into function to edit array

Tags: c++, arrays, struct, segmentation-fault

Im working on a project to make a word scramble game and currently working on putting the letters in an array of strings. Currently not using any pointers and I worry that that is the cause but I am fairly confused at this point because my assignment requires me to use structs.

Any help would be greatly appreciated,
Thanks.

struct definition:

```
struct puzzle {
int cols;
int rows;
string puzzle[];};
```

loadPuzzle function

```
void loadPuzzle(puzzle p){
char c;
p.puzzle[5];
for(int i = 0 ; i <p.rows ; i++){
   p.puzzle[0] = "                      ";
   for(int j = 0 ; j<p.cols ; j++){
      iFS >> c;
      if(!c=='\0')
         p.puzzle[i][j]=c;
   }
 }
 }
```

main function

```
int main(int agrc, char* args[]){
//setting default file name to make it easier for testing
string sourceFile = "testfile.txt";
puzzle p;
puzzle *puzz = &p;
//space left to add another do if need be
   do{
      cout << "please enter scramble name: ";
      getline(cin, sourceFile);
      cout << endl;
      iFS.open(sourceFile.c_str());
      if(!iFS.is_open()){
         cerr << "Couldnt open file" << endl;
      }
   }while(!iFS.is_open());
p.cols = getPuzzleCols();
p.rows = getPuzzleRows();
cout << p.rows << p.cols;
loadPuzzle(p);
// displayPuzzle(p);  
}
```

Comment: This data member isn't valid C++: `string puzzle[];`. Fix that, and some of your problems might go away.

Comment: Does your code even compile? I can't even compile the code you pasted because of the issue posted above.

Comment: `p.puzzle[5];` I was about to say does that compile, but I guess it does, it just tries to read `p.puzzle[5]` (which doesn't exist) and throw away the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you can declare an array with no size

```
struct puzzle {
int cols;
int rows;
string puzzle[];};
```

You can't give it a size later through `p.puzzle[5];`. This line doesn't actually do anything.

Instead what the no-sized array does is allows one to access memory *beyond* the end of the struct as if it were an array. This can be useful for clever/old-school ways of allocating arrays, but isn't good for modern C++.

What you should do instead is learn to use `std::vector`.

Start with:

```
struct puzzle {
int cols;
int rows;
std::vector<string> puzzle;};
```

Then read up on how to add elements to it (such as `resize` or `push_back`).

Or if you can't do that for some reason, then you need to give the array its size in its declaration so that it really exists. For example:

```
struct puzzle {
int cols;
int rows;
string puzzle[5];};
```

Comment: `string puzzle[];` is valid in C but not C++.

Comment: I really shouldn't have put the puzzle[5], I had that in there just for testing. My problem is that I cannot use vectors and I have to allow it to work with different sized arrays based on the input file. I have a getPuzzleRows() method that I use but it does not let me declare string puzzle[getPuzzleRows()] so I do not know what to do.

Comment: @w.b In that case, you need to learn about dynamically allocated arrays so that you can do stuff like `string* puzzle = new string[getPuzzleRows()]`

Comment: Awesome, really appreciate the help. got it working after a little bit of research into pointers and dynamically allocated arrays.